# XML XSLT idref tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have this XML file below

XML

```
<geo>
   <state id="georgia">
     <capital idref="atlanta"/>
     <citiesin idref="atlanta"/>
     <citiesin idref="columbus"/>
     <code>30294</code>
   </state>

   <state id="florida">
     <capital idref="miami"/>
     <citiesin idref="atlanta"/>
     <citiesin idref="orlando"/>
     <code>12345</code>
   </state>
```

I know to get the data for the zip code in my XML file I just do that below and it will print out all the zip codes in the that xml file. How can i do the same thing to get the capital or citiesin because it has the idref tag and I tried doing it similarly as I did with zip code but it doesnt work. Im not sure how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="state">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="code"/>

</p>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="code">
  Zip Code: <span style="color:#ff0000">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="state">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="code"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="capital"/>
            <xsl:text>Cities: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="citiesin/@idref">
                <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <xsl:text>Zip Code: </xsl:text>
        <span style="color:#ff0000">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="capital">
        <span><xsl:value-of select="concat('Capital: ', @idref)"/></span><br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Im trying to get all of the citiesin in one line and the capital to display on a new line. I got all of the citiesin in one line working by replacing the break with a comma and a span style but how can I display the capital on a new line? I tried copying that same set of code you used above to do it but i get an error for some reason.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "." in your template above is selecting the text. You just wish to get the attribute value. Here's one of the templates:

```
<xsl:template match="capital">
  Capital: <span style="color:#ff0000">
 <xsl:value-of select="@idref"/></span>
 <br />
</xsl:template>
```